# Android and no XML

Tags: android, xml, security

I'm a beginner and building android apps and I was wondering, do i have to use XML to build a successful android app?

how does it affect how to user uses the application?
Without XML, is it less secure?, especially if the application requires log in credentials?

I was not able to find any examples online referring to other methods of building an android app than with XML.

Sorry if my question feels stupid, but i would really appreciate a response. Thank you.

Comment: You can use Java to build the UI, but... meh, I wouldn't in most instances.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to build your UI without xml although you can that. And the strings which you're going to use on the UI should be stored in string.xml for better maintenance and multiple languages support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i have to use XML to build a successful android app?

Well, you need XML to create a native Android app *at all* since you need an Android Manifest, which happens to be a XML file. It's also a good practice to use String resources and not to use hardcoded strings throughout the app. But I'm sure you are asking weather you need to build your layout in XML, or not right?
In this case you don't have to use XML, but I would recommend you to since building your entire layout dynamically can be a lot more difficult than building it in XML(my personal opinion). But it's possible of course.

> how does it affect how to user uses the application?

If you do everything right then a XML build layout can be the same as a dynamically-build one. (There are even a few API advantages building the layout with java than with XML)

> Without XML, is it less secure?

No.

Comment: Well, say for example i am building an application that collects name, address and credit card information. Using the Android SDK, I would like to collect this information from a user and secure it. Would it help me to do that or there are other things i would need to look into?

Comment: It makes no difference if you you add your layout dynamically or via XML in this case since you won't be saving the information unencrypted(I assume). So the way you retrieve this information is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

> do i have to use XML to build a successful android app?

No. You can make your entire layout in Java, and have it look exactly the same (apart from a couple of themeing options that can only be applied through XML).

However, you must have some XML files, like AndroidManifest.xml, and your widget XMLs if you have a homescreen widget.

> how does it affect how to user uses the application?

In 99% of the cases, they won't notice.

> Without XML, is it less secure?

This question makes no sense.

> especially if the application requires log in credentials?

Again, this makes no sense.

How you build your UI is unrelated to security.